# Driver installation Edimax EW-7811 UTC

Tags: pi-3, wifi, raspbian-stretch, driver

I am trying to install the drivers for Edimax EW-7811UTC on Raspberry Pi3 running Stretch lite. I followed the steps given in [How to install EW-7811 AC600 Series and EW-7822UAC adapters on Raspberry Pi](https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000032146-how-to-install-ew-7811-ac600-series-and-ew-7822uac-adapters-on-raspberry-pi)

However I don't find the drivers installed.

[image: Screenshot of airmon-ng]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text itself into the question.

Comment: Please paste command output as text

Comment: I'm trying to use the same hardware on the pi-zero-w as an upgrade radio to wireless ac.  The source provided by edimax lacks ARM processor instructions in the config.  Still researching this.